# do you know of a service that records the remote desktop session that is saved as a video online where I can log on and view?

Tags: desktop, remote, screen-recorder

Is there a website that allows users to create an account as an administrator, then create accounts for employees (similar to skype), and when an employee signs in, a desktop remote viewing session will begin recording.  When they sign out, the session is saved as a video clip in a file where the administrator can play, ff and rw, and see the time passed?

I realise software companies offer a product similar to this for purchase, which records activity from a company server, but I am looking for a website that offers this service online, to clients that can access the recorded sessions on the website.

Answer (score 1):

Teamviewer. Simple and easy.

http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx